# Can't access certain websites via wifi/ethernet, although ping is okay, and they work via LTE

Tags: networking, router, http

Since yesterday, I can't connect to some (very few) websites, like

```
http://www.theguardian.com/
```

via my fixed internet connection, on Orange FR network, via Livebox 4 Sagecom router (while they're up when I connect via LTE mobile network).

`ping` works but no browser can open the page:

```
    $ ping www.theguardian.com

    Pinging prod.i.ssl.global.fastly.net [151.101.120.67] with 32 bytes of data:
    Reply from 151.101.120.67: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
    Reply from 151.101.120.67: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=56
    Reply from 151.101.120.67: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
    Reply from 151.101.120.67: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=56

    Ping statistics for 151.101.120.67:
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
        Minimum = 19ms, Maximum = 41ms, Average = 25ms
```

(when using LTE tethering, ping resolves to the same IP, just with different TTL).

The problem happens to some extent with other websites: the page loads, but some images (depending on the subdomain) are not loaded.
Images from `server1.foobarcdn.com` work but not images from `server2.foobarcdn.com` etc.

Apart from `ping` I tried:

- different browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox),
- different devices (Windows laptop, Android phone),
- lowering router security level to the lowest possible,
- restarting the router,
- doing factory reset on the router,
- disabling IPv6 on my laptop,
- setting DNS to 8.8.8.8 on my IPv4 connection,

all to no avail: using landline connection, I can't open the website in my browser.

Whereas if I connect via LTE mobile connection (also Orange) from the mobile phone (or from laptop via tethering), it works fine.

To sum up:

- wifi via Orange router: `www.theguardian.com` does not load on **any device, any browser**
- ethernet via Orange router: `www.theguardian.com` does not load still
- LTE mobile connection (also Orange): `www.theguardian.com` loads fine

Can there be any possible cause other than some issues on my ISP's side or faults in the router? 
What can I do to try to resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you restart/reset the router?

Comment: Setting DNS to 8.8.8.8 may not resolve all DNS issues.

Comment: Update: I first restarted the router, then did factory reset. The issue persists.

Comment: @jakub.g did you manage to solve the problem? I am experiencing something very similar.

Comment: @kuri the problem went away (I would be *very* mad if it didn't for 1.5 year:) but unfortunately I don't remember the details. Probably it self-fixed after a few days.